# Pie 9.0 Low Battery Notification Not Working (Moto G7)

Tags: notifications, settings, battery-life, system, motorola

New Moto G7 running Android Pie 9.0

Everything else works fine. The issue I'm having is with the Low Battery Warning sounds and notifications. Simply put, I want the most annoying low battery indicator in the world and it's just not doing that. All I get is the little red battery in the corner. And that's if I'm not watching videos or playing games. Otherwise, it just silently lets me use up the battery and then shuts down. I've already tried:

- Exhaustively scouring the internet for any answers
- Turning up the volume
- Plugging and unplugging the charger
- Enabling charging sounds
- Checking all the boxes and radio buttons in App info/System UI
- Turning the phone off and on again
- Restarting the phone
- Clearing the cache
- Looking everywhere for more answers
- Posting my issue on the Motorola Community website
- Factory resetting the phone (a last resort that did not work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR; You either get battery saver, or notifications; not both.

There seems to be an issue with the Android Pie release, or a subsequent patch. When the "Battery Saver" function is turned on, it automatically disables the "Low Battery Notification" features. Or, the battery saver fires and prevents the low battery notification from firing by default. "Save the battery" instead of making noise, popping up a message, and vibrating. I turned off the "Battery Saver/Turn on automatically" function and now my phone interrupts whatever I'm doing to let me know I need to plug in soon.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup [MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) app to detect battery saver and notify you about it in the way you want it to be.

Add a new Macro with these conditions:

Trigger: Battery/Power > Battery saver state > Enabled

Actions: as you wish. You can setup a notification with a sound, vibrate, or try other actions.

Constraints: none

Save the Macro and try the battery saver manually. MacroDroid should be working for you in that case.

Note: [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) app can also do the same thing but it doesn't have battery saver state context. Instead, you can define battery range for your context.

Solution tested in OnePlus 6 running Android Pie.